# Is there a way to execute code on session destroy in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm trying to implement time tracking for my custom CRM. Base idea is to use toggle button so I could store "start_time" and "end_time" for that specific task, and the difference between those two will represent time spent. But what if user closes the browser or shutdown PC, is there an event for session destroy so I could insert "end_time" after session is destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

You cant really rely on a laravel session to be removed instantly if it expires, since I believe it is based on a lottery system which cleans up the sessions like 1 in every 100 requests.

I suggest implementing something with an ajax ping, so that you can tell that the pinging has stopped when the user closes its browser. There isnt really another way to know whether the user has closed their browser.

Answer (score 0):

A session is not necessarily destroyed when the window is closed. You could define some events for `onbeforeunload`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   // Send a request to the server to notify it of the window being closed/refreshed
}
```

Or you can do some polling as Flame suggested, but I consider that approach to be unclean, as it creates some network noise one would like to avoid.

You can also establish a duplex channel, like a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) channel,so your server will know when it's broken.

Comment: i havent used `onbeforeunload` yet, I wonder how stable it is and if you can make sure an ajax-request is actually completed in there

Comment: @Flame as far as I know it's stable, but you can do some experiments if you want. As about an AJAX request, it's pointless to wait for an AJAX request to complete when the window is closed. It's feasible to only send it.

Comment: hm yes I guess the browser can send it and just neglect the response

Comment: @Flame exactly. If the request cannot be sent, then the user might have no access to the Internet at that point of time. A short polling solution has the potential of being more accurate, but if there are more users, one pays the price in terms of server load. This is why I consider that solution to be unclean. If we want a clean solution without wasting resources, then a WebSocket connection is to be used. The interruption of the connection could be catched at server-side, there are no drawbacks whatsoever and a WebSocket connection has so much more benefits.